# Embed python code in PHP failed

Tags: php, python

I want to embed python code in PHP. For that it ask me to install python package for PHP using pear installer by the command

```
# pecl install python
```

when i run this command its failed install every time, showing the error message..

```
configure: error: Please specify path to Python distribution files
ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/python/configure' failed
```

i dunno what to do, or how to specify the path.

Comment: this question belongs to serverfault.com because it deals with server configuration.

Comment: are python and its dev libraries installed on your computer through your package manager?

Comment: Take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/jparise/php-python/issues/5).